# What should be the CSS Selector to find count of comments in a YouTube video using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, css-selectors

#### Set chromedriver on path and paste URL of the search:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('**************') 
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=youtube+keywords&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D")
```

#### Retrieve video links:

```
user_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]') <br>
links = []<br>
for i in user_data:<br>
            links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

#### Create a new df with new info we will collect:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['v_search', 'v_id','v_comments'])
```

#### Find remaining data with Selenium:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
v_search = "Youtube Keyword" 
for x in links[:1]:<br>
        driver.get(x)<br>
        v_id = x.strip('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=') 

        ### HERE IS MY QUESTION.
        v_comments = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#count > yt-formatted-string"))).text

        # Throw information in the dataframe we defined before (fills row per row).
        df.loc[len(df)] = [v_search,v_id,v_comments]
        sleep(0.5)    #in seconds
```

[image: Snapshot of the whole code]

[Traceback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCTcs.png)

Comment: Selecting a CSS selector can be sometime a frustrating task. Use this extension on chrome to retrieve % accurate results of CSS Selectors. Refer this : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-unique-css-selector/lkfaghhbdebclkklgjhhonadomejckai?hl=en

Comment: Do you want just a number of comments or what? Thanks.

Comment: There are comment and reply to comments. How do you plan to organize such cases?

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. It's weird because, in the same way, I can extract other video information (e.g. video likes, dislikes, etc) but for some reason, I cannot do the same for the number of comments. I posted an additional snapshot of the code that extracts info (I've tried with XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, and others). Please let me know if you need more context to help me answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS Selector is working for me:

`#count>.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer`

Tested like:

```
document.querySelector("#count>.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer").innerHTML;
```

The result will be like -- x Comments.

PS: Better to use the `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition. So, in your case, it will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


...
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
v_comments = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#count>.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer"))).text
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. It's weird because, in the same way, I can extract other video information (e.g. video likes, dislikes, etc) but for some reason, I cannot do the same for the number of comments. I posted an additional snapshot of the code that extracts info (I've tried with XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, and others). Please let me know if you need more context to help me answer the question.

Comment: @ErikHren, check out my updated answer, it's working for me. I have added 1 line of code for scrolling the page down (after that, the counter of comments will be visible).

Comment: @ErikHren, if my answer is fixed your problem, please, accept it -- check a tick near my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Google Chrome you can use the 'inspect' mode to get the XPATH, see image below:

[image: Chrome XPATH]

Wich gives me the XPATH:

`//*[@id="count"]/yt-formatted-string`

so:

```
lol = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="count"]/yt-formatted-string')))
print (lol.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what the problem might be if someone runs into the same time exception error with selenium. The way I think selenium works is the following. The driver opens a website and looks for the element you are looking for. In my case its count of comments on a youtube video. If Your element is down the page where you cannot see it, selenium might not be able to pick it up. So, what I did is make the driver scroll to the bottom of the page, wait for a few seconds so it loads. While that might be enough for some I still had some problems in some cases. So I also then make it to go up for 300 (I assume screen pixel size) and wait for it to load. If this still does not work for you, consider making selenium move a mouse while it loads, which could trigger the thing to load.

```
# we will make it rest for 5 seconds
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
# scroll to the bottom 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)") 
# Wait to load page
time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
# scroll to the bottom 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 1080)") 
# Wait to load page
time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
```

ALSO, open the driver window so you can see it make its magic. That might also make it extract info. Hope this helps. I am so happy to figure it out.